# Sending POST request to JENKINS

Tags: svn, jenkins, http-headers, http-post

i have a requirement in which i am trying to build a **presentation layer on top of jenkins.
from my JSP i will take the SVN repository ,username and password and will make a post request to Jenkins on the correct URL to validate them**. 
the url which is it taking is

```
http://160.110.143.38:8080/job/basicjob/descriptorByName/hudson.scm.SubversionSCM/postCredential
```

After a lot of searching on the internet i did not find any answer . . . Please suggest me how achevie the same .
Or you can suggest a workaround as well ...

Thanks in advance

Comment: What kind of validation are you looking for? Could you define it in as much detail as you can?

Comment: while configuring a job in Jenkins i can give my SCM policy (CVS,SVN,Git,...) . if a choose SVN i need to provide the repoURL,and username and password on a different page with URL-

Comment: while configuring a job in Jenkins i can give my SCM policy (CVS,SVN,Git,...) . if a choose SVN i need to provide the repoURL,and username and password on a different page with URL-[link](http://localhost:8080/job/basic-job-demo/descriptorByName/hudson.scm.SubversionSCM/enterCredential?http://localhost) so the requirement says i send username,password and repoURL and validate if they are correct. I checked how Jenkins is storing the username,password for SVN(jenkins_home/jobs/jobName/subversion.credentails) and another interesting file is ($jenkins_home/hudson.scm.SubversionSCM).thanks

Answer (score 0):

As explained on Jenkins job REST API help page, you can post certain things using curl. Please have a look at below page if you haven't done it yet.

```
http://160.110.143.38:8080/job/basicjob/api/
```

And here is a basic build triggering example. This may not be the exact answer you're looking for but it at least shows how you can trigger a build using POST.

```
curl -X POST http://http://160.110.143.38:8080/job/basicjob/buildWithParameters?PARAM1=${PARAM1}&PARAM2=${PARAM2}
```

Comment: thanks for reply . i know how to use Jenkins REST api . the issue here is somewhat different . I want to validate the svn repository , username and password via posting request to Jenkins .

Answer (score 0):

```
public boolean constructCredentialStore(String jobName, String password,
        String userName, String url) throws IOException, JAXBException,
        ClientProtocolException, ParseException {
    DefaultHttpClient httpclient = new DefaultHttpClient();
    HttpPost httppost = new HttpPost("http://150.110.35.38:8080/job/"
            + jobName
            + "/descriptorByName/hudson.scm.SubversionSCM/postCredential");

    MultipartEntity reqEntity = new MultipartEntity(
            HttpMultipartMode.BROWSER_COMPATIBLE);

    reqEntity.addPart("url", new StringBody(url.toString()));



    reqEntity.addPart("kind", new StringBody("password"));

    reqEntity.addPart("username1", new StringBody(userName.toString()));

    reqEntity.addPart("password1", new StringBody(password.toString()));

    reqEntity.addPart("Submit", new StringBody("OK"));

    httppost.setEntity(reqEntity);

    System.out.println("executing request " + httppost.getRequestLine());
    HttpResponse response = httpclient.execute(httppost);
    HttpEntity resEntity = response.getEntity();

    if (resEntity != null) {
        String page = EntityUtils.toString(resEntity);
        System.out.println("PAGE :" + page);
        return true;
    }
    else return false;
}
```

Have used a POST request with multi-part data . .Only checking for SVN username , password amd URL